# Play youtube m3u8 live stream in Chrome

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, hls.js

I am trying to play some youtube live stream by getting it's manifest m3u8 file.

Currently I used youtube-dl to get m3u8 and then hls.js to play it. It works fine with most of files from their examples but not youtube.

Here is a [Codepen working example in Chrome (will take some time to load)](https://codepen.io/askhento/pen/oNdVmjV?editors=1011).

If I change the url with m3u8 file to results of:

```bash
youtube-dl -f 94 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21X5lGlDOfg
# here you will get current link which will expire in some time
```

I get 403 error, which seems to me that I have to use some policy. Another clue came in from VLC player which works great with all live stream links I've tried so far.

Comment: Have you first look at [hls.js issues](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues) to see if they already have noticed your problem? If not and if you haven't posted such an issue, then you should definitely open one.